# rotation of elements within a list

Tags: java

I have a List which contains 5 element [a,b,c, d, e]. Based on user selection I would like to change the display order and would like to know if there are functions which can give me a newly ordered list.

```
e.g. If user selects d, e to move 1 position up, the resultant order will be [a,b,d,e,c]
e.g. If user selects b, e to move 1 position up, the resultant order will be [b,a,c,e,d]
e.g. If user selects b, d, e to move 1 position up, the resultant order will be [b,a,d,e,c]
```

Is there an out of the box function which can do this?

Comment: I don't get your requirements - specifically I don't think I understand what you mean by "move one position up". In the first example, I would expect the output to be [a,b,d,e,c] based on your description.  Can you clarify?

Comment: you are right, I made a mistake and I have corrected the question

Comment: moving a position Up implies that the element gets moved to the left and the element before that moves to the right in position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you're swapping adjacent elements.  Basically,`x=a[i]; a[i]=a[j]; a[j] = x;`

Comment: I am using Collections.swap to implement this logic now

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Circular Linked List](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Circular_linked_list_in_java_Sample)
You'd put the user selection at index 1 and traverse remaining list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple requirement for which neither JDK-collections, common-collections or google collections have an answer.

I would suggest writing one :)

Comment: I have seen Collections.rotate but it rotates the entire list. My logic seems to be flawed to solve this issue and hence this question